# Implement transfer learning on niftynet

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, niftynet

I want to implement transfer learning using the Dense V-Net architecture. As I was searching on how to do this, I found that this feature is currently being worked on ([How do I implement transfer learning in NiftyNet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768864/how-do-i-implement-transfer-learning-in-niftynet)).

Although from that answer it is quite clear that there is not a straight way to implement it, I was trying to:

1) Create the Dense V-Net

2) Restore weigths from the .ckpt file

3) Implement transfer learning on my own

To perform step 1, I thought I could use the niftynet.network.dense_vnet module. Therefore, I tried the following:

```
checkpoint = '/path_to_ckpt/model.ckpt-3000.index'
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None,1,144,144,144])
architecture_parameters = dict(
    use_bdo=False,
    use_prior=False,
    use_dense_connections=True,
    use_coords=False)

hyperparameters = dict(
    prior_size=12,
    n_dense_channels=(4, 8, 16),
    n_seg_channels=(12, 24, 24),
    n_input_channels=(24, 24, 24),
    dilation_rates=([1] * 5, [1] * 10, [1] * 10),
    final_kernel=3,
    augmentation_scale=0)
model_instance = DenseVNet(num_classes=9,hyperparameters=hyperparameters,
                             architecture_parameters=architecture_parameters)

model_net = DenseVNet.layer_op(model_instance, x)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <type 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [None, 1, 72, 72, 24]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

So, the question is:

Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Transfer learning has been added been added to NiftyNet.

You can select which variables you want to restore through the `vars_to_restore` config parameter and which variables to freeze through the `vars_to_freeze` config parameter.

See [here](https://niftynet.readthedocs.io/en/dev/transfer_learning.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

A simple transfer learning can be achieved with restoring weights from existing model in the way that you set the parameter `starting_iter` in `[TRAINING]` section of your config file to the number of pretrained model. In your example `starting_iter=3000`.

This will restore the weights from your model and new iterations will start with this initialisation.

Here the architecture of your model has to be exactly the same, otherwise you will get an error.

For more sophisticated transfer learning or maybe also fine tuning where you can restore only a part of weights, there is a great implementation [here](https://github.com/aleks-djuric/NiftyNet/tree/add-transfer-learning). It will be probably merged with official niftynet repository very soon, but you can already use it.